# Denormalized DataFrame to nested documents

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I need to process some data from a Spark DataFrame to an ElasticSearch index.

My DataFrame :

```
scala> source.printSchema()
root
 |-- dialogue_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dialogue_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dialogue_text: string (nullable = true)
scala> df_echanges.show
+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|           dialogue_id|        dialogue_number|               dialogue_text|
+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|                 DIAL1|                      1|                     Hello !|
|                 DIAL1|                      2|                        Hi !|
|                 DIAL1|                      3|               How are you ?|
|                 DIAL1|                      4|              Fine and you ?|
|                 DIAL1|                      5|                      Fine !|
|                 DIAL2|                      1|       Hello ! How are you ?|
|                 DIAL2|                      2|                      Fine !|
+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
```

My destination is an ES index, "dialogue" field is nested :

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "dialogues": {
           "properties": {
               "dialogue_id": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "dialogue": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "dialogue_number": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "dialogue_text": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So I need to transform my DataFrame into this :

```
scala> dest.printSchema()
root
 |-- dialogue_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dialogue: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dialogue_number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dialogue_text: boolean (nullable = true)
```

How to do this ?

Thanks !

Geoffrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to do this would be to escape the world of DataFrames for your transformation. After the transformation is done you can convert back into a DataFrame and do whatever it is that you want to do with the data in your destination schema.

I would try something like the following:

First make sure you have some case classes declared that represent your destination schema (this is the easiest way, but naming conventions for case class members do violate the "standard" conventions of Scala code):

```
case class DialogueElement(dialogue_id: String, dialogue: Array[InnerDialogueElement])
case class InnerDialogueElement(dialogue_number: String, dialogue_text: String)
```

Then run the following transformation (mainly using the RDD API):

```
// Transform to RDD and group by first column (= index 0)
val groupedRdd = source.rdd.groupBy(row => row.getString(0))

// Map the grouped values into a case class that represents
// your inner dialogue elements
val mappedInnerElementsRdd = groupedRdd
  .mapValues(group => group.map(r => InnerDialogueElement(r.getString(1), r.getString(2))))

// Map everything into a case class that fully represents your destination schema
val finalRdd = mappedInnerElementsRdd.map({ case (dialogueId, innerElements) => DialogueElement(dialogueId, innerElements.toArray) })

import sqlContext.implicits._ // needed for calling toDF()

val finalDF = finalRdd.toDF()

finalDF.printSchema() // should print your desired schema
```

Instead of declaring the above case classes with the exact field names (e.g. "dialogue_id"), you could also name those members differently and manually tranform back from RDD into DataFrame using:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(yourRDD, yourSchemaContainingTheFieldNamesYouWantToHave)
```

Hope this helps :)

PS: Using `groupBy` with RDDs implies that each group has to fit into main memory entirely!